# Bootstrap center alignment not properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a `<div>` that displays 9 columns in the browser with proper width and height horizontally, but currently the `<div>`s are shown correctly and properly aligned, but not centered.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    &nbsp;
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: -11px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 13px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 12px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 13px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 16px;">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 16px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Sidenote following edit: Keep in mind for code to display correctly it must be indented at least 4 spaces from the left. Or, highlight your code and press the `{ }` button to auto-indent it.

Comment: You do realize that in bootstrap that the total number of columns shouldn't exceed 12 right? Your medium and extra-small rows have 54 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can offset columns in bootstrap using 'offset' classes http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

But as 9 doesn't divide equally into 12 (i.e. you can't offset by col-md-1.5) you may be better to create your own class of div within a .container/.row/.col-md-12 (whatever you decide depending on your layout requirements) and set the max width to 75% - colours are just for example purposes.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.mynewdiv {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mynewdiv">
    <p>75% width div here</p>
  </div><! --/.mynewdiv -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood please check if this solution helps you

https://jsfiddle.net/akshaybhende/DTcHh/6730/

Please increase fidddle screen width and check as the demo will be small and lg-grid wont apply.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 center-div">

     <div class="col-sm-4 inner">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">1
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">2
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: -11px;">3
    </div>
        </div>

     <div class="col-sm-4 inner">
     <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">4
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 13px;">5
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 12px;">6
    </div>

        </div>   

    <div class="col-sm-4 inner">

    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 13px;">7
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 16px;">8
    </div>
```